# ZIP retrieval from database - how to optimize it with indexes

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, zip, indexing

I got following database:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/zips/

What I would like to do is optimize it. Basically when user enters ZIP code I want to retrieve Long and Lat.

I use Spring > Hibernate > MySQL setup.

The question is how do I configure the MySQL and Hibernate to speedup the retrieval. I'm not that familiar with indexes so little explanation would be also very helpful.

Ideally if I could create optimized (compressed) database construct instead of MySQL table, that would be ideal, since this will be used only for reading.

Comment: This table `WorldCities` does not have zip code fields. Am I missing something? Are you planning to get zip code from city/state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first run a SQL explain on the query and see the cost of the SQL. After that you want to see how the database matched on the rows. Did it do a full table scan or did it to a index match (and there are variations on index matches)? You want to avoid full table scans always unless you have like only few hundreds rows in the table. In that case the database might decide to do a full table scan.

Once you have that information you can determine what index you need on your table. Then over a period of time as the table grows more in data you want to run the table scans again to see if the indices are still good.

Here is a good [tutorial](http://forums.spry.com/howtos/1345-using-mysqls-explain-command.html) to get you started.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not familiar with hibernate. In general I go by using explains and working with the DBA to create index itself.

Comment: Ideally there should not be a difference between the SQL that you manually create vs the one hibernate generates. Can you trace the SQL that hibernate generated and do an explain on that to see if it's doing an index match? If that happens I assume you are good on that front.

Comment: Although I am not extremely familiar with hibernate but as far as I know the query optimizer is supposed to figure out to use index when needed.